# Python, min among first objects in lists

Tags: python, list, min, playing-cards

I have a very particular problem, I have a deck of cards. The deck is a list of lists of tuples, each internal list is a suit with card tuples (suit, value), sorted smallest to largest(2-Ace). I would like to find the smallest card in the deck. So basically I want to take the first object from each suit, and find the smallest. Short of an horridly ugly for loop, what is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: can you put some code in order we can help you in a better way?, seems like maybe you can use min builtin function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min` takes a key function. You can use this to get the first element to use it as the comparison:

```
min(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Just tested your code, I may have not been clear enough in my description but the number, which is really what we are focusing on is the number so your code should be min(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0][1])

Comment: You didn't give an example, so we had to guess your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
min(suit[0] for suit in deck, key=lambda suit,value: value)
```

Since you noted that the suits are sorted, you can simply get the first item of each suit list to get the smallest value of that suit; then compare those first values using `min()` with the `key` argument specified to look at the value portion of each.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that the deck list is created as below:

```
TheHearts = TheSpades = TheDiamonds = TheClubs = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"j","q","k","a"]
TheDeck = [TheHearts, TheSpades, TheDiamonds, TheClubs]
```

the following line can provide you the first object of the first list:

```
print TheDeck[0][0]
```

or even if you make a dictionary, then you can use the names instead of numbers:

```
TheHearts = TheSpades = TheDiamonds = TheClubs = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"j","q","k","a"]
TheDeck = {'TheHearts':TheHearts, 'TheSpades':TheSpades, 'TheDiamonds':TheDiamonds, 'TheClubs':TheClubs}
print TheDeck['TheHearts'][0]
```